# PostgreSQL: full text search increase rank when matched lexeme first in the tsvector

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

There is a `tsvector` which is defined like this:

```
'foo':3A,6A,9A,12A,15,18,21,24
'bar':1A,4A,7A,10A
```

When this `tsvector` being matched by `tsvector @@ $$'foo':* $$::tsquery` it got bigger `ts_rank_cd` compared to `tsvector @@ $$'bar':* $$::tsquery`.

I would expect `bar` having bigger rate because it is `1st` compared to `foo` being `3rd`.
Is there a way to change this behaviour?

(psql 13 is used on google cloud sdk)

`tsvector` uses `gin` index.

Thanks

Comment: Were you expecting it to do that automatically because of something in the docs?

Comment: no, just a gut feeling that it should work automagically. is there a way to force it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a token to the front of the tsvector, and also add it to the front of the query.  I've made the token be not a real English word, to make it less likely to be found naturally in the strings.

```
select ts_rank_cd('startzz:1'::tsvector || 'foo:3A,6A,9A,12A,15,18,21,24 bar:1A,4A,7A,10A'::tsvector,
    'startzz & foo:*');

 0.060606062

select ts_rank_cd('startzz:1'::tsvector || 'foo:3A,6A,9A,12A,15,18,21,24 bar:1A,4A,7A,10A'::tsvector,
    'startzz & bar:*');

 0.18181819
```

Or of course you can just write our own ranking function, using whatever principle of operation you think makes sense.